# How to synchronize the horizontal scroll bar of jQuery.SerialScroll with the slider contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slider

I am using jquery [SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) on my web page to slide around 20 images and it's working perfectly fine.Now i want to do this:

As their are 20 images to slide so a scroll bar comes under the sliding images(or i can say at the end point of the sliding div) and this scroller automatically updates as images slides,so now i want that if a user click on that scroll bar and slide the slider manually and leave the scroller on 10th images then it should start it next scroll from the 10th images and then continue to scroll.

So please tell me or suggest me how can i do this?

I think it can be done by detecting a if a user clicked on scroll bar and scroll manually then i need to detect how many images passed then start the scroll again by triggering an event.

But please give me some idea in terms of code ?

-Thanks

Comment: To help you I need to know 1. how many images are in view. 2. is the gallery full width or overflow:none. 3. are all the images same width.

Comment: here is the answer: 1.only 1 image at a time in view   2.http://pastebin.com/MZVHeGNH     3.no not all images of same width but it can be if necessary       my sliding div name is "slideshow" and all images are in a "li " tag

Comment: Can you build a gallery HTML-CSS layout in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: You can start from here: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/waFXt/

Comment: yes i can but it will take some time but i think i got the idea(form your 3 points ) what you wan to do.SO i am trying the same,hope i will get the sucess

Comment: I am already making the gallery... will take some time I got to do other things too. I'll make you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write our own tiny serial-scroll! 

And ... a nice Image slider:

- Stop on mouseEnter
- Restart on mouseLeave
- During manual slide it controls the image mostly visible (more than 50% on screen!)
- Start slider again from the mostly visible image

### [Gallery DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/32fFR/3/)

Comment: hey your code works fine in firefox but in google chrome it's not working.I think it's not understanding mouseup event.can you please figure out the reason?

Comment: thanks for try but i think it's still not working in chrome and now the slider is also not auto running,have you checked it in chrome

Comment: ya it's working thank you very much so i need to change mouse up to mouseout,i think the mouseup is not working due to race condition between mouseup and scroll.Any ways thank you very much

Comment: It was a conflict cause we already had a 'stopped' gallery while 'mouse-upping' the slider. Now the same effect is given to the `mouseout` listener. In any case Chrome have problems with the combination of `scroll` and `mouseup`. :)

Comment: ya but i am using your code in a different manner in my project but anyways it's working fine now :-)